# Converting ArrayList Strings of to Characters?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char, multidimensional-array

So I have an arrayList of Strings imputed by the user.I also have a 2d array of chars : private char[][] puzzle ; I need help changing the Strings to characters so I can enter them into the 2d array can anyone help??

```
public class WordSearchPuzzle
{
    private char[][] puzzle ;
    private ArrayList<String> puzzleWords ;
    private int letterCount = 0 ;
    private int gridDimensions;

    public WordSearchPuzzle(ArrayList<String> userSpecifiedWords)
    {
        this.puzzleWords = userSpecifiedWords ;

    }

    private void createPuzzleGrid()
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size() ; i++){
            letterCount = puzzleWords.size() + letterCount ;
        }
        gridDimensions = letterCount * 2;
        puzzle = new char[gridDimensions][gridDimensions] ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change each string to a [charArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

```
for(String item : ArrayList){
  item.toCharArray();
}
```

Comment: will that put the array of chars to an array or an arrayList

Comment: @user1323808 If you look at the documentation it states `Returns:
a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.`

Answer (score 0):

Tagged as homework. Like in your previous questions, I'll ask: did you try anything yet? How do you plan to solve this? What is your current problem?

I'll give you an idea. createPuzzleGrid() method inialises the puzzle array for you. Note how they calculate the dimensions from the list of words. This should point you in the right direction: how to copy characters from the list of words into the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WordSearchPuzzle {

    private char[][] puzzle ;
    private List<String> puzzleWords; //note: don't use a specific implementation (e.g. ArrayList) when you define a List  

    public WordSearchPuzzle(List<String> userSpecifiedWords)
    {
        this.puzzleWords = userSpecifiedWords ;

    }

    public void createPuzzleGrid()
    {
        puzzle = new char[puzzleWords.size()][];
        for(int i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size() ; i++){
            puzzle[i] = puzzleWords.get(i).toCharArray();
        }
    }   


    public void debugPuzzle(){
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(puzzle));
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> userWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        userWords.add("word");
        userWords.add("longlongword");
        userWords.add("hello");

        WordSearchPuzzle puzzle = new WordSearchPuzzle(userWords);
        puzzle.createPuzzleGrid();
        puzzle.debugPuzzle();
    }

}
```

result

```
[[w, o, r, d], [l, o, n, g, l, o, n, g, w, o, r, d], [h, e, l, l, o]]
```

Comment: will that make a difference to the size of the 2d array.I want to keep it to the length of the characters in the arrayList * 2 so here is my code for that:private void createPuzzleGrid()
    {
        int i, itemLength;
        String item;
        for (i = 0; i < puzzleWords.size(); i++) {
            item = puzzleWords.get(i);
            itemLength = item.length();
            letterCount = letterCount + itemLength;
        }
        gridDimensions = letterCount * 2;
        puzzle = new char[gridDimensions][gridDimensions] ;
    }

Comment: OK, I understand, that this result does not fit for you: `[[w, o, r, d], [l, o, n, g, l, o, n, g, w, o, r, d], [h, e, l, l, o]]`. But I still don't get what are you trying to achieve? What is your purpose with `puzzle[][]`? I'm not sure `char[letterCount * 2][letterCount * 2]` is useful, maybe you need `char[maxWordLenght][maxWordLenght]`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ok what im trying to achieve is a word search puzzle using a 2d array where the user inputs a arrayList of Strings and we have to convert the strings to chars because the 2d array will only accept chars and then enter the words(as chars) randomly into the 2d array.Thanks a million for the help!If you have skype you can add me to chat easier!

Comment: I see. How would you define the size of the 2d array, in which you will try to put words randomly? (I mean in layman's terms)